# display first page of pdf in image format

Tags: php, pdf

I would like to display  first page of an uploaded PDF as an image with a link on it to the PDF file

can you help me doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=230074

It's using imagemagick but it seems to work :) Hope this helps!